# how to customize kendo UI for asp.net mvc for development for codeSnippet Features

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

all . I've searched but could not find . **I want codeSnippet Features in kendo ui for asp.net mvc Editor**

I want use from a text editor With the ability to write code or I want use from kendo ui component for asp.net mvc .

But i think it is not complete , Because it not support for developer . i want thing as Ck Editor .

For example : [CkEditorForDeveloper][1]

i need Code Spinet     for kendo ui editor in asp.net mvc .

how to use Code Spinet in kendo ui Editor ? Please help me for do it . :(
thankful

Comment: You want to extend the editor as a custom control?

Comment: Yes Ross Bush . I want to add that tag code in the editor. I need this ( <pre><code> </pre></code>.

Comment: @RossBush   as this  => http://ckeditor.com/features

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link to the KenodUI Editor snippet documentation. Is this what you mean by snippet?

[Kendo .NET MVC Editor Snippets Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/editor/snippets)

Comment: Buss i want this  .Snippets(snippets => snippets
            .Add("C#Code", "<pre><code></code></pre>")
             )   but its not work for me